# Linux special device does not exist when I mount

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I am using Centos8 with standard specs like 8GB ram and 4CPU and 250 GB Space.
When I finished the installation I get automatically 2 folders, 1 70GB and 1 with 160GB.
I want to merge them both to one.

I have changed my partition system from this:

```
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 236.9G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl-home 253:2    0 159.1G  0 lvm  /home
```

To this:

```
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 236.9G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0 229.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Thanks to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150279

But when I mount -a the directory I get the following error:

```
mount: /home: special device /dev/mapper/cl-home does not exist
```

Shouldnt this also be deleted? Because I think that if I reboot the server it will go in maintance mode. How can remove that error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the second answer to that question you link to

Answer (score 0):

Mount points in linux are mostly defined in /etc/fstab. So you would need to edit the /etc/fstab file and remove the entry, which is trying to mount /home

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

Remove the entry and save the file. Running mount -a again will not produce such an error